# "Share This" text is a bit.. bland and awkward

Tags: feature-request, area-51, commitment-phase, share-this

I decided to use the "share this" feature to see if any of my friends on facebook would maybe join the Gaming commitment bit(I have a lot of gamer friends).

The problem I have is that the text is a bit bland and awkward

[alt text http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/9038/sharethis.png](http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/9038/sharethis.png)

This is posted on my wall. So there is no "personal" you. Why not rephrase this a bit where it's more like an announcement rather than a personal message? Also, why not bring in actual content?

Something like:

> ```
> Gaming - Area 51 - Stack Exchange
> area51.stackexchange.com
> ```
>
> Check out this proposed Q&A site for
>   passionate gamers from all platforms
>   (computers and consoles). If it sounds
>   interesting then you can "Commit" to
>   the site so that you can be notified
>   when it is created.

Comment: "Who's the ad wizard who thought of that!?"  Does anyone think it sounds exciting to check out a _proposed_ site and sign up to be notified (sometime in the future) when it's created?

Comment: @Ward if you knew a *proposed* mall(or whatever establishment) was opening in your area, wouldn't you want to be notified and/or support it?

Comment: @Ward it's not a live site yet, so what else can you call it?

Comment: No, I probably wouldn't be interested in a new (whatever), based on a very short announcement and a very sketchy outline of what it was.  I think that what you see on the page for a site in commitment  isn't very compelling.